# How would I prevent a for loop from firing more than 10 times every second?

Tags: swift, api, for-loop, timer

I have created a request to OnRadar using an array of information to create geofences. However, my attempts to create a time/delay do not prevent the for loop from firing more than ten times per second, which the API cannot handle.

```
func setUpGeofences(){

    for object in geofenceArray{

      let params: [String: Any] = [
          "description": object.name,
          "tag": object.tag,
          "externalId": object.externalID,
          "type": "circle",
          "coordinates": [object.lat, object.long],
          "radius": object.radius,
          ]

      let headers = ["Authorization: Key"]
      let rq = Alamofire.request("https://www.onradar.com/api/v1/geofences", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
          .responseJSON { response in

              print(response.result.value)
              print(response.result.error)
          }
    }
}
```

This is my function with the for Loop. I've had a look at a few examples but when I tried to apply them to my own work, I was unsuccessful. Furthermore, how would I stop the loop from running once it has created geofences for each location in my array?

Comment: I would contact OnRadar support and ask if there is API support for creating multiple geofences in a single network call.
For example, ask if it is possible to pass an array for geofences to create into this request.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple way to do the next one after the request finishes:

Change `geofenceArray: [Geo]` to whatever type `geofenceArray` is

```
func setUpGeofences(geofenceArray: [Geo]) {
    if let object = geofenceArray.first {
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            "description": object.name,
            "tag": object.tag,
            "externalId": object.externalID,
            "type": "circle",
            "coordinates": [object.lat, object.long],
            "radius": object.radius,
            ]

        let headers = ["Authorization: Key"]
        let rq = AlamofireRequest("https://www.onradar.com/api/v1/geofences", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in

                print(response.result.value)
                print(response.result.error)
                // do the next one
                setUpGeofences(geofenceArray: Array(geofenceArray.dropFirst()))
        }
    }
}
```

It isn't guaranteed to be slower than 10 times per second, but this might be good enough for now.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, is there a simple way to only allow the loop to run the number of times that's equal to `geofenceArray.count` ?

Comment: My code will do I that. It keeps removing the first element and then stops when it runs out of elements.

Answer (score 0):

They're difficult these situations, try this:

```
var i = 0
let geofencesArray = ["firstObject", "secondObject", "thirdObject"]

func iterate(array: [String]) {

  if i > array.count-1 {
     return
  } else {
      print(array[i])
      i+=1
      iterate(array: array)
  }
}

iterate(array: geofencesArray)
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question—making the process recursive doesn’t significantly affect its timing.